# Angular does not recognize component in the same module

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend, angular-module

After creating a module by Angular CLI I tried to create a component in the same module and using it. The problem is that I always get "error NG8001: 'component' is not a known element". To create the module I used the command: `ng g component modules/module1/components/component--module=modules/module1`

I have all the necessary imports on my module file.
These are my files

## Module1.module.ts

```
import {AppModule} from "../../app.module";
import {AppRoutingModule} from "../../app-routing.module";
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {FleetManagerComponent} from './module1.component';
import {FleetManagerRoutingModule} from './module1-routing.module';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import { Component} from './components/component/component.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    Module1Component,
    Component
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    Module1RoutingModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AppModule    
  ],
  exports: [
    Module1Component,
    Component
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [Module1Component]
})
export class Module1{
}
```

## Component.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  templateUrl: './component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./component.component.css']
})
export class componentComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { /* TODO document why this constructor is empty */  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // TODO document why this method 'ngOnInit' is empty

  }
```

## module1.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-module1',
  templateUrl: './module1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./module1.component.css']
})
export class FleetManagerComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

## module1.component.html

```
<app-component></app-component>
```

Comment: Don't use keywords like `Component`.  This will very likely clash with `Component` from `'@angular/core'`. And you're declaring `Component` not `componentComponent `

Comment: The 'component' is not the name of the component, I just named it now to post here @AndrewAllen

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring `Component` not `componentComponent`

```
import {AppModule} from "../../app.module";
import {AppRoutingModule} from "../../app-routing.module";
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {FleetManagerComponent} from './module1.component';
import {FleetManagerRoutingModule} from './module1-routing.module';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
// import componentComponent 

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    Module1Component,
    componentComponent // <--------- changes
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    Module1RoutingModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AppModule    
  ],
  exports: [
    Module1Component,
    componentComponent // <--------- changes
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [Module1Component]
})
export class Module1{
}
```

Comment: I was already importing the component i just named it as 'component'. But tried renaming it and I get the same error.

Comment: Please update question to reflect minimal example. As posted my answer should work for your error